# Which preposition can I use with a verb?

Tags: verbs, prepositions

Certain verbs go with certain prepositions. How can I find out which preposition goes together with a verb? Specifically, can "to" be used with "display"?

> John displayed the slideshow to Mary.

Comment: Unfortunately, (i) the sentence is not idiomatic - a slide-show is not *displayed* to a person. (ii) To display can be followed by many prepositions.

Comment: ... This is really strange, because 'displayed them to all the villagers', 'displayed them to a wider audience' ... _are_ idiomatic (though _slideshow_ doesn't really work). 'John put on a slideshow for Mary' is more natural here. The DO seems restricted, and the IO (if there is a DO; '_the male displayed to the female_' works) usually needs to involve a widish audience.

Comment: [Well selected Google n-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=displayed+them+to%2Cdisplayed+them+before%2Cdisplayed+them+for%2Cdisplayed+them+in+front+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdisplayed%20them%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisplayed%20them%20before%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisplayed%20them%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisplayed%20them%20in%20front%20of%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdisplayed%20them%20to%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisplayed%20them%20before%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisplayed%20them%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisplayed%20them%20in%20front%20of%3B%2Cc0)...

Comment: can be of use (search the data below them for actual examples), as can looking at example sentences dictionaries provide (eg [CollinsCobuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/display): 'He displayed his scars to the twelve members of the jury.')